# Dynamically load SubVI frontpanels

Tags: user-interface, labview

I want to display multiple SubVIs (each one has a set frontpanel with controls and indicators) in my main VI. The problem is: usually only 2 or 3 are active at the same time, the rest are deactivated. 
Let's say I got an array of VI references for the active SubVIs. Is it possible to display the SubVIs in a table, where each SubVI gets its own row?
I'm basically looking for a container similar to a Tab Control, but instead of tabs I want to display the VIs row-wise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best choice for you is sub panels. http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/D587067E18E0E70186256D44007B91FE

Example:
https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-18164

Also there is nice way with xcontrols, but it is complicated and takes more time to implement. Anyway below is link about xcontrols: 
http://www.ni.com/tutorial/3198/en/

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to place a Sub Panel (which shows a VI's front panel) in an array control, but I was able to place it and its VI reference in a *cluster*, and then place that in an *array*:

[image: Array of Cluster of VIRef and Sub Panel]

After that, you could set the VI Ref's visibility to hidden, and tweak the array's chrome. Going further, I don't know if LabVIEW provides a way to give that subpanel a VI reference when it's in a container, so your mileage may vary.